# PaintComponent is not called

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to build a GUI that represents a graph that is called from a JSON file. But the `paintComponent` method is never called. Why is that?

EDIT: graphics an image are declared as class fields

This is my code for `JPanel`:

```
public Panel(DirectedWeightedGraph graph) {
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.graph = graph;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (this.graph == null) return;
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    paintVertex(g2d);
    paintEdge(g2d);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Create a new "canvas"
    this.image = createImage(800, 800);
    graphics = image.getGraphics();

    // Draw on the new "canvas"
    paintComponent(graphics);

    // "Switch" the old "canvas" for the new one
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
```

This is my code for `JFrame`:

```
 public UserWindow(DirectedWeightedGraphAlgorithms graph) {
    super();
    graphAlgo = graph;
    this.panel = new Panel(graphAlgo.getGraph());
    this.add(this.panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    InitWindow();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This should be the first line `super.paintComponent(g);` in your `paintComponent(...)` method, also you're calling the wrong method you're calling `paintComponentS` and not `paintComponent` (without the S), but for better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: thank you! I removed the 's' but it's still not working... thank you for the advice of the minimal example, I'll remember it the next time

Comment: If you actually want help with this question don't wait till next time to provide an MRE, you should create a brand new project where you can reproduce the problem, then post the code here so we can test the same code and see why it isn't working. We don't know what `DirectedWeightedGraph` is or looks like, we don't know how `paintVertex` or `paintEdge` do or what `graphAlgo` is, we know nothing about your program and can't test it in our machines

Comment: `Don't override paint()`. All the custom painting logic should be in the pantComponent() method. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples.